# Hangup After First Ring Using Asterisk Call Files

Tags: asterisk

Default Asterisk configuration (only sip.conf changes).

I use call files for calling and I need to hangup after first ring while every dial.

WaitTime: 4 seconds doesn't work sometimes, since it's counting from the beginning (connect to SIP provider etc) and the client doesn't even receive the call.

**00359894000001.call**

```
Channel: SIP/flowroute/00359894000001
Extension: 00359894000001
WaitTime: 4
```

Comment: One might wonder what use this might have except for wangiri scam (lure the called user to call back a heavily charged number)

https://www.cnn.com/2019/05/07/us/fcc-robocall-scheme-scam-warning-trnd/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way predict connection time and count how much ring was at called side. Ring create by endpoing equipment, you have no control/info about it.

Comment: That was I worried about. But I think Asterisk recognizes it somehow, I just can't find a way to do it...

Comment: please read SIP RFC. only signal you can got is 180 Ringing. Which mean "softswitch accepted call and now ringing". After softswitch can be enother softswitch or 10 of same softswitches. So no any way say how much time between ringing and actual ring on other side. Note, on asterisk you even can't got info about 180 Ringing. So no way for sure. Forget anything you know about analog PBX. Asterisk is VOIP one.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection time for the SIP provider etc is constant you should just check what it is and add it to your 4 seconds.